# Is there an exact options in KVM like in vmware the reservations, limits and shares for Network, CPU, memory and IO

Tags: kvm-switch

VMware was the options to set the reservations, limit and Shares for Network, CPU, Memory and IO.
I'm unable to find these options in KVM(I'm using Ubuntu 16.04)
Please help to find these options for each one if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main locations you’ll be dealing with that cover all the various options you listed.

For setting network adapters, virtual networks, and network shares, do the following:

1. Start off by going to the Virtual Machine Manager main window
2. At the top click the Edit menu tab
3. Choose the Connection Details option
4. From there you can choose from 4 tabs: Overview, Virtual Networks, Storage, and Network Interfaces.

For the rest of the settings, such as CPU, memory, IO, NIC, USB, etc., do the following:

1. From the Virtual Machine Manager main window, choose whichever virtual machine you want to configure and click Open.
2. In the next window, which is the virtual machine you just opened, at the top click the View menu tab.
3. Most likely the Console radio button will be currently selected. Right under that you’ll see the Details radio button. Choose that one.
4. This will bring up a new window with all the various CPU, memory, IO, etc settings over on the left side; these are all similar to the VMware settings you’re used to.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the exact settings as in VMware. 
I found some virsh command which can set limits. 
Example for Memory :
 virsh # memtune domain-id --hard-limit kilobytes which is similar to Limit in VMware.
Couldn’t find exact option for reservation or min-guarantee memory in KVM. May be its not supported. 

Likewise for I/O found an option for limit(very close)
virsh blkdeviotune domain vda total_iops_sec #
Which makes me wonder if Shares and Reservation is not supported by KVM at all

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question about **CPU reservation** through the years of work with Linux virtualization which was related to linux scheduler mechanisms. Still there is no suitable mechanisms to reserve CPU resources in KVM like it was done in VMware. Just vCPU pin to CPU host can partitionally solve this case, but it's not the same thing.

Basically you always need to be sure that your virtualisation host is not overloaded. Most of hypervisors manuals recoments to not load your virtualization host more that 70 percents.

That's was the painful part of question.

Now about the whole VM resource management that you asked about, it's quite easy.

- **GUI:** you can find a lot of info about *virt-manager*: https://virt-manager.org/ Just `sudo apt install virt-manager && virt-manager`
- **Console:** a lot of options (incuding extra) available using `virsh`: https://libvirt.org/manpages/virsh.html

I bet you'll love console version later, it's pretty good to automate your VMs deployments.